# Need to replace all commas in an AWS lambda using Java 8

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, replace, aws-lambda, replaceall

First I should lead with how very inexperienced I am with this language.  Everything I've tried has blown up.  It doesn't seem to like .replace or .replaceAll anyway I've tried to use it.  I've used Pattern and Matcher. no go.

I need to place this code in an already work class that is reading a ResultSet from a query and it's sending it to a .csv file.  Here is the code I'm working with.  My latest try you'll see between the comments //All of Nikki's mess and //end of Nikki's mess.  I'm really going out of my mind if someone could help shed some light.  Just seems like such a simple thing but the language barrier is real!!

public class CSVUtil {

```
public static final String QUOTE = "\"";
public static final String DELIMETER = ",";

public static String convertToCsv(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
    StringBuilder csv = new StringBuilder();

    while (rs.next()) {

        // all Nikki's mess
        // between the comments
        
        String comments = rs.getString("ImageAnnotation");
        //Pattern pt = Pattern.compile(",");
        //Matcher match = pt.matcher(comments);
        //while(match.find()){
            comments = comments.replaceAll(",","");
        //}
        System.out.println(comments);
        
        //end of Nikki's mess

        csv.append(QUOTE).append(rs.getString(1)).append(QUOTE);

        for (int i = 2; i <= rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); i++) {
            csv.append(DELIMETER).append(QUOTE).append(rs.getString(i) == null ? "": rs.getString(i)).append(QUOTE);

        }

        csv.append(System.lineSeparator());
    }
    return csv.toString();
}
```

}

Comment: I was hesitant about posting here.  it's a tough crowd.  I've read sooooo many questions about solving this and none of them are working so I thought there was something more specific about it being done in AWS Lambda java, hence the title including it.  Apologies for my inexperience.  The only error log I have is this:

Comment: "errorMessage": "java.lang.NullPointerException",
  "errorType": "java.lang.NullPointerException",
  "stackTrace": [
    "com.sgk.redshift.ingestion.CSVUtil.convertToCsv(CSVUtil.java:54)",
    "com.sgk.redshift.ingestion.RdsDataService.exportBMRDataTo(RdsDataService.java:80)",
    "com.sgk.redshift.ingestion.LambdaFunctionHandler.handleRequest(LambdaFunctionHandler.java:27)",
    "com.sgk.redshift.ingestion.LambdaFunctionHandler.handleRequest(LambdaFunctionHandler.java:18)"

Comment: Doesn't really tell me anything other than my line 54 is where the error is occurring. and that is this line
 comments = comments.replaceAll(",","");

Comment: thanks - I've already read this explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to resolve.   I added the replaceAll into this line:

csv.append(DELIMETER).append(QUOTE).append(rs.getString(i) == null ? "": rs.getString(i)).append(QUOTE);

csv.append(DELIMETER).append(QUOTE).append(rs.getString(i) == null ? "": rs.getString(i).replaceAll(",","")).append(QUOTE);

Looks to have done the trick.

Comment: How are you building your Lambda Java function - are you building it via Eclipse tool or using the Java runtime API in a Maven project (which is better way).